# will_paginate: can't figure out how to customize inside bullets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, will-paginate

I am trying to make a custom page list using will_paginate.  I have succesfully created the previous and next buttons.  I'm now trying to create the buttons in between but a having trouble figuring out how.

Here is my code for the previous and next buttons:

```
<ul class="pagination-styler">

    <% if @options.previous_page %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to params.merge(:page => @options.previous_page), style: "aria-label: previous;" do %>
            <i class="ba ba-left"></i>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    Page <%= @options.current_page %> of <%= @options.total_pages %>
    <% if @options.next_page %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to params.merge(:page => @options.next_page ), "aria-label" => "next" do %>
                <i class="ba ba-right"></i>
            <% end %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

This renders the following:

[image: pagination menu]

I want to replace where it says "page 2 of 3" with icons I have that look similar to the previous and next buttons and will have specific page numbers.  I can't find any helpers or way of doing this provided by will_paginate, but i'm sure there must be a way.

Does anyone know how to customize the actual link buttons?  I'll need to wrap them in "li" and add the  inside the links.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by overriding the `tag` method in `will_paginate`

You do this with a .rb file in `/app/helpers` I called mine `pageoverride.rb`

Inside would look something like this

```
module Pageoverride
  class PaginationListLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer
    protected
      def tag(name, value, attributes = {})
        string_attributes = attributes.inject('') do |attrs, pair|
          unless pair.last.nil?
            attrs << %( #{pair.first}="#{CGI::escapeHTML(pair.last.to_s)}")
          end
          attrs
        end
        "<li><#{name}#{string_attributes}>#{value}</#{name}></li>"
      end
  end
end
```

I've only added `<li></li>`around the return statement. Then to use this your pagination call should look like this `<%= will_paginate(@options, :renderer => Pageoverride::PaginationListLinkRenderer) %>` You should be able to add any classes to that `<li>` there as well.